# Comparing excel cells using .value doesnt not match even though the data is identical

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have looked through all the other similar questions, but am unable to find any solution to my problem.

I am comparing two excel sheets for their cell.value, using vbs. when i run my script, the data shows as not identical, even though visually it looks exactly the same. Its numeric data with custom formatting.

75662.726506 this is the actual cell value, and what appears in the column is 75,663. Both the excel sheet displays the exact same data.

here is the code i am using to compare

```
For Each cell In objMyWorksheet1.UsedRange

If cell.Value <> objMyWorksheet2.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
        cell.Font.ColorIndex = 46
       Flag = "False"
 End If
Next
```

The cell has a Custom format in excel - [$-en-US,1]#,##0;(#,##0)

One of the files is in the .xls format while the other is .xlsx .

i have compared length, ascii, format etc and everything matches. Not sure what else i could check.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
AD

Comment: Most likely the two cells are not identical. But you don't provide sufficient information to reproduce your problem. Provide the contents of the **formula bar** when you select each of the cells (by copy/pasting it as an edit to your question), and also provide the script you are using to determine if they are identical.

Comment: Thanks Ron Rosenfeld. i added my code, its simply comparing the values in the cell. Also i do not see any formulas when i select the cell. The reports are generated by the developer and i only receive the excel files to compare and test

Comment: Where is the copy/paste from the formula bar?  With the code you've provided, it only has to be unequal once and it will forever be marked with a red color.  And you should also read about the potential pitfalls of using `Precision as Displayed`

Comment: Thanks. I did read about the Precision as displayed and is not something we will be using. The formula bar shows 75662.726506 on both files i am comparing. I am saving the marked rows in a new file, so i have the results. But it doesnt touch the original files.

Comment: Also we are trying to figure out if the excel type may be the issue one being .xls and the other .xlsx file. But for some reason my script isnt working...i am getting an Object required error when its setting one of the worksheets for this line Set objMyWorksheet2= objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)   it was working fine earlier and started throwing the error, though i made no changes at all. Any help is highly appreciated, i have tried everything possible :(

Comment: If your script is not working, that makes me wonder whether, at the time it seemed to be "working", it was not comparing what you thought it was comparing. You've only shown a portion of your script. But so far, from what you've posted, I cannot reproduce your problem.  `xls` vs `xlsx` should not result in the issue you are seeing.  Can you upload two worksheets that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I fixed the script issue. it was opening two excels with same name, so once i changed the name for one of the files its resolved. I will try to add some test data to mimic my issue and attach. It did work when it compared, because i am asking the code to change font color if there is a mismatch and save a copy. Thank you so much for taking time to answer my somewhat silly questions/issues. Appreciate it.

Comment: I await an example of the problem, so I can reproduce it here, and hopefully discover what is going on.

Comment: i changed my code to use cell.text and its works fine. I checked with the developer and they do not care abt the decimals as they are rounding off the numbers, so it was okay to compare text displayed rather than the data in the formula bar when i click into the cell. I am not sure how to attach files here, so unable to add samples, sorry this is my first time trying to add files.

Comment: I do have new question and not sure if i can can ask here. Turns out the files i am comparing will also have graphs and charts. Will the code with cell.text work in this situation?

Comment: You cannot "attach" files. You need to upload them to some public sharing site and then post a link here.  Your code does not compare graphs or charts.  I suggest you try what you want to do before posting a new question, though.

Answer (score 1):

At First run this function and see the difference between two cells:

```
Function FindDifPoint(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim difFound As Boolean
    difFound = False
    If str1 <> str2 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(str1)
            If Mid(str1, i, 1) <> Mid(str2, i, 1) Then
                difFound = True
                result = "the equal part is:<" & Mid(str1, 1, i - 1) & ">, and the different part in str1 is:<" & Mid(str1, i, Len(str1) - i + 1) & ">"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If difFound = False Then
            For i = 1 To Len(str2)
                If Mid(str2, i, 1) <> Mid(str1, i, 1) Then
                    difFound = True
                    result = "the equal part is:<" & Mid(str2, 1, i - 1) & ">, and the different part in str2 is:<" & Mid(str2, i, Len(str2) - i + 1) & ">"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If difFound = False Then
                result = "Any thing is same, I dont know what happend, check the box I told you"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        result = "Two Cells are equal"
    End If
    FindDifPoint = result
 End Function
```

for test I wrote two numbers `=pi()` and `3.14`  in Range `A3` and `B3` with same format to find the difference with formula `=FindDifPoint(A3;B3)`
[image]

if that solution didn't work, I suppose to check the `Set precision as displayed` in `Options/Advanced` and then see the result.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Sharif. i added this to run against my excel and it went into the loop for updating the precision value. Once i did that, my script ran perfectly. I am checking with my developers if this is something we should be doing or acceptable. But this was the only loop it went into when running the script. thanks for the help.

Comment: you can send me the file to filnd the problem, if you want.